# Google Slides API: replaceAllLinks?

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

In my implementation, I go through a loop to duplicate a slide and then update the text and images of each new slide using `ReplaceAllText` and `ReplaceAllImages`. I can do that in one batchUpdate. I wish I could do the same and "ReplaceAllLinks" but could not find anything to do that. Any ideas ?

Comment: You mean link URLs that are included in your text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to replace all links in a Google Slides using Slides API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there is no methods for directly achieving "ReplaceAllLinks". So it is required to use a workaround. In this answer, I would like to propose the following workaround.

1. Retrieve the object IDs you want to replace the link using the method of presentations.get.
2. Replace the links of the retrieved object IDs using `updateTextStyle` and `updateShapeProperties` of the method of presentations.batchUpdate.

In this case, 2 API calls are required.

#### References:

- [UpdateTextStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetextstylerequest)
- [UpdateShapePropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateshapepropertiesrequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Mkou Thank you for replying. Although this might be resolved by the Google's future update, I apologize for the current Google's specification.