# How to replace all hyperlinks using google slides api?

Tags: google-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

Referring to the Google slides api official documentation couldn't find a way to replace all links.

I found one work around: [Google Slides API: replaceAllLinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885305/google-slides-api-replacealllinks)

I am able to replace text, images but not links.

Any help shall be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the URL the hyperlink is pointing to? Do you have any code you're working on?

Comment: Yes you're correct. Basically the link url should get updated. Code i am referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885305/google-slides-api-replacealllinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyperlink URL is represented by the `link` field of [TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/text#textstyle).

This [Link](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#Page.Link) contains the field `url`, which refers to the URL this is pointing to. You should update this field when calling [UpdateTextStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetextstylerequest).

As an example, your request body could be something like:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateTextStyle": {
        "objectId": "your_object_id",
        "style": {
          "link": {
            "url": "your_new_url"
          }
        }        
      }
    }
  ]
}
```